# If I have 10,000 stocks to sell with 23 B market cap

Tags: stocks, trading

If I have 10,000 shares of a company with 23B market cap, and if i want to sell all the stock can it be sold at one shot? meaning r there enough buyers to buy my stocks? what if there are not enough buyers? I am new to stock trading please consider this a newbie question.

Comment: Terminology: 10,000 shares of the stock of a company.

Comment: http://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/aon.asp may be a useful term to note here if you want the order to be that all or none of the shares are sold.

Comment: @keshlam - please edit the question to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will almost certainly be able to sell 10,000 shares at once. The question is a matter of price. If you sell "at market" then you may get a lower price for each "batch" of the stock sold (one person buys 50, another buys 200, another buys 1000 etc) at varying prices.

Will you be able to execute a single order to sell them all at the same price at the same time? Nobody can say, and it's not really a function of the company size.

The exchange has what's called "open interest" which roughly correlates to how many people have active orders in at a given price. This number is constantly changing alongside the bid and ask (particularly for active stocks).

So let's say you have 10,000 shares and you want to sell them for $100 each. What you need is at least 10,000 in open interest at $100 bid to execute.

By contrast let's say you issue a limit order at $100 for 10,000 shares. Your ask will stay outstanding at that price and you'll be filled at that price if there are enough buyers. I you have a limit sell order at $100 for 10,000 shares the strike price of the stock **cannot** go to $100.01 until all of your sell orders are filled.

Comment: I bought shares via trading company site, but I never sold any shares in my life. I want to does it give me option to sell at the current price? or does it give me price I want to sell it at?

Comment: We can't tell you what the "trading company site" does or doesn't support. Ask them

Comment: @user206168 any modern brokerage site should allow you to set either a market or a limit sell order. I would contact them for details.

Answer (score 2):

First a quick terminology correction: I believe you're proposing selling 10,000 shares of the stock of a company, not "10,000 stocks".

When you sell, you need to decide whether you're selling for a specific minimum price or just selling for whatever price you can get.

If you set a specific lower limit on asking price, then if people aren't interested at that price it doesn't sell. Which may mean you sell only a few shares, or none if your asking price isn't considered reasonable.

If you want to sell independent of price, then as you begin to flood the market with your shares, the price you get per additional share may decline until it finds a buyer. What that lower limit is will depend on what people think the stock is currently worth.

This is one of the many complications I don't want to deal with, which is why I stick with index funds.

Comment: I bought shares via trading company site, but I never sold any shares in my life. I want to does it give me option to sell at the current price? or does it give me price I want to sell it at?

Comment: We can't tell you what the "trading company site" does or doesn't support. Ask them.